# adding more than one script into an html page

Tags: javascript, conflict

when adding the two following  scripts into an html page , neither of them work,i guess there's something like script conflict,my question is how to overcome this?
the first script is:

```
            $('document').ready(function(){

            $('#form').validate({
                    rules:{
                        "name":{
                            required:true,
                            maxlength:40
                        },


                        "message":{
                            required:true
                        }},

                    messages:{
                        "name":{
                            required:"This field is required"
                        },


                        "message":{
                            required:"This field is required"
                        }},

                    submitHandler: function(form){
                      $(form).ajaxSubmit({
        target: '#preview', 
        success: function() { 
        $('#formbox').slideUp('fast'); 
        } 
    }); 

                    }

            })

        });
```

and the second script is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var j = jQuery.noConflict();
    j(document).ready(function()
    {
        j(".refreshMe").everyTime(3000,function(i){
            j.ajax({
              url: "posts.php",
              cache: false,
              success: function(html){
                j(".refreshMe").html(html);
              }
            })
        })
    });
   j('.refreshMe').css({color:"red"});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

See the documentation: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

`var j = jQuery.noConflict();` "returns" the $ variable's value to whatever it was before jQuery appropriated it. In this case, it happens to be `undefined`. This breaks the first script, since it's now trying to use the $ variable, which is undefined(you should have had a lot of errors popping up in your console, which you should add to your question).

As to why the second script stops working, it's hard to tell without having more information what you mean specifically - how do you know it has stopped working, are there any javascript errors, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use more script tags in the HTML, your problem is that you want to use jQuery before you initialize it. Make sure that you first add jQuery to your HTML and only then you use it.